# How to change state to previous state in bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have sigIn function that get data from Api and move to another screen if request is successful and if request is not successful then show alertDialog

I change state and before fetching data I show CircularProgressIndicator to make user know that data is fetching.

But when alertDialog window pops up and I close it then CircularProgressIndicator doesn't disappear. How to remove WaitingSignInAuth and show me Scaffold with inputs

When error comes then I emit ErrorSignInAuth but why there is WaitingSignInAuth to.. Why ErrorSignInAuth doesn't replace WaitingSignInAuth or it should work differently?

This is the code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is WaitingSignInAuth) {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ));
        }
        if (state is ErrorSignInAuth) {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Bad request"),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Error")
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text("Close"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context); // If i press it then alertDialog diappears but not the loading circle
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
          );
        }
      },
    );
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that you `showDialog()` twice. First is shown when `WaitingSignInAuth` state is fired, and the second one when you receive `ErrorSignInAuth`.

So `Navigator.pop(context);` in the "error" alert dialog closes only the `showDialog` that you've triggered in `if (state is ErrorSignInAuth)`, the second dialog, which contains progress indicator is still visible.

To easy fix it, you can change your code to:

```
TextButton(
  child: const Text("Close"),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
)
```

But in my opinion thats not the best fix to your issue. IMO you don't need to show ProgressIndicator for `WaitingSignInAuth` in the dialog. Adjust your UI in the way, that the container with progress indicator will be displayed over it, but this doesn't need to be a dialog.